# Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian is laggy

Tags: performance, raspberry-pi, raspbian, lag

I am having some issues with my RPi2. As I said in the title I have Raspbian installed. The system runs smoothly when I navigate files etc. But when I try to use the Internet Browser OR Navit (I am working on a project and I want to use the RPi as a navigator) then the system gets laggy and very very slow. I also notice that in the right top corner the cpu usage goes about 30% (sometimes more).

Raspbian is installed in a 16Gb Class 10 SD Card. I have expand the system via raspi-config and I have about 9 gigabytes of free space. I also have HDMI, keyboard and a wireless mouse connected.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using wireless - cpu going up 30% doesn't sound unusual for a web browser starting up. Web browsing speed is more tied to your internet speed and RAM than system cpu and SD card.

Comment: Does wireless mouse slow down the system? I use ethernet cable for internet browsing. But anyway..tha lag is happening whithout internet connection too. Is there any raspberry configuration settings or tips for a big higher performance?

Comment: A Pi 3 might solve problems.